# Manually "compressing" a very large number of boolean values in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, data-structures

We have a data model where each entity has 600 boolean values. All of this data needs to travel over the wire from a node.js backend to an Angular frontend, via JSON.

I was thinking about various ways to optimize it (this is an internal API and is not public, so adherence to best practices is less important than performance and saving bandwidth).

I am not a native Javascript speaker, so was hoping to get some feedback on some of the options I was considering, which are:

- Turning it into a bitfield and using a huge (600-bit) `BigInt`.

  Is this a feasible approach? I can imagine it would probably be pretty horrific in terms of performance
- Splitting the 600 bits into 10 integers (since JS integers are 64 bit), and putting those into an array in the JSON
- Base64 encoding a binary blob (will be decoded to a UInt8Array I'm assuming?)
- Using something like Protobuf? It might be overkill because I don't want more than 1-2 hours spent on this optimization; definitely don't want to make major changes to the architecture either

*Side note: We don't have compression on the server end due to infrastructure reasons, which makes this more complicated and is the reason for us implementing this on the data level.*

Thanks!

Comment: Curious, what kind of data model needs 600 fields?

Comment: @jmargolisvt It's a static tree-like structure. It's actually only 4 booleans, belonging to a group of properties each of which belong to parent properties, etc. It's basically time-series data with 4 boolean values at pre-defined time intervals. The model is complex, but currently it's just an array of booleans that travels over the wire and gets reconstructed back into the proper object on the Angular end.

Comment: Note that bit-wise operators convert `Number`s to 32-bit in javascript. Also, `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is between `2^52` and `2^53`.

Answer (score 0):

as Evan points out, transforming your boolean for example into a single character for true="t" and false="f", the 600 boolean will become a joined string of 600 chars which can very well be split into 3 strings of 200 of the sizes, then once received on the front just concatenate the transit and if you want to recover your Bollean values ​​from the string, with a simple reg it becomes possible.
I don't know how the data is set and then obtained, just changing this parameter to which I think needs to be automated.
Once the final string is obtained on the front here is an example of reg ex which can convert your string to an array with your 600 boolean. It is also possible to define indexes by defining an object instead of the array.

```
function convert_myBool(str)
   {
      /*var reg = new RegExp('.{1}', 'g');
      var tmpTab = str.replace(reg, function(matched){
            return matched == "t"?true:false;
      });*/
      //map is best 
      tmpTab = str.split('').map((value) =>{
        return value == "t"?true:false;
      });
      return tmpTab;
   };
```

I wrote this dynamically so of course it can be pondered, improved replaced etc. Hoping to have helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Can it be sorted in any way? If there are boolean values that always occur in conjunction with a related value you may be able to group them and simplify.

Depending on what your use for that data is, you may be able to cache some of the it or memoize based on usage frequency. There would be a space tradeoff with caching, however.